# Image causing table cell height to extend

Tags: html, css

I hate CSS like the plague.

I have a table header, with several table cells inline. This works perfectly until I start trying to add an image to one of the cells, which causes the height of the div to extend but I have absolutely no idea why.

[Example of blank table cells working perfectly.](https://codepen.io/tombarton/pen/mRRwQj?editors=1100)

[Example of the demon that has been haunting me all day.](https://codepen.io/tombarton/pen/PWWmRm?editors=1100)

```
.header {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeff3;
    .burger-menu {
        width: 75px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; 
        background: url("https://s23.postimg.org/o8wb4i5u3/1484768142_menu_alt.png");
        background-size: 30px 30px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-indent: 0px;
    }
}

.outer {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.outer-icon {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    height: 75px;
    width: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 2px solid #eeeff3;
    img {
        height: 100%;
    }
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.search-bar {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 80%;
    input {
        height: 75px;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        border-right: 2px solid #eeeff3;
    }
}

.inner {
    width: 75px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Can anyone put me out of my misery?

Comment: CSS is a good servant but a bad master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height` from `.outer-icon`. I don't know that it's ever a good idea to apply `height` to a table cell. Set `vertical-align: middle;` on `.search-bar` and `.outer-icon`.

Comment: Would it seem to strange to confess my love for you? You've slain the beast. A million thank you's.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve everything but changing `display` on `add-friend` seems to improve things:

```
.add-friend {
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/75/75/face);
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    display: inherit; <- this here thingy
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNNdYw

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to set an explicit height on `.outer-icon` because you are wrapping a lot of elements with it and should let the inner content set the height.

```
.outer-icon {
  height: 75px; // remove this line!!!
}
```

Then set the hamburger menu to be absolute inside of its relative parent div.

```
.burger-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 25px;
}
```

Cheers